# Binary number string max 1's

Tags: javascript

Why does this code is not accepted by the hackerrank test which expects 3 as a result, whereas converting the number 439 to a binary string carries out 2 as a result.

The task: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-binary-numbers/problem?isFullScreen=true

My code (failing at test case 2 - > input=439):

```
function main() {
    const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    const nBinary = n.toString(2);
    const nBinarySplit = nBinary.split("");
    let count = 0;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < nBinarySplit.length; i++) {
        if (nBinarySplit[i] === '1') {
            count++;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    console.log(count);
}
```

Comment: `439` -> `110110111`, so the maximum number of consecutive 1's is `3`, your code return `2`. You always consider only the first sequence, excluding other possible.

Comment: Oooh, now I get it.. "CONSECUTIVE" is the word here. Thanks.

Comment: Basically use a highest count, reset a count and count 1's and see if your count is higher than the previous highest count when you hit a 0 or the end of the length.

Comment: I know this is probably unrelated, because the task at hackerrank specifically mentions the range of number, but since the question does not specifically ask for it, I would liketo add that the `Number.toString(2)` method will not work correctly for negative numbers

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski , yes, this is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a shortcut solution:

```
function main() {
    const n = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    const nBinary = n.toString(2);
    const nBinarySplit = nBinary.split("0");

    let result = nBinarySplit.reduce((r,s) => r > s.length ? r : s.length, 0);

    console.log(result);
}
```

Comment: or in one line :) `const main = () => console.log(Math.max(...parseInt(readLine(), 10).toString("2").split("0").map(_ => _.length)));`